pthread_cancel on blocking read doesn't work
Simple code snippet hanging forever:
#include <csignal>
#include <mutex>
#include <print>
#include <iostream>

void *routine(void *arg) {
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, nullptr);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, nullptr);

    std::istream &input = std::cin;
    int value;
    std::cout << "Reading" << std::endl;
    input >> value;
    std::cout << "Reading done" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th, nullptr, routine, nullptr);

    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "Cancelling thread" << std::endl;
    pthread_cancel(th);
    std::cout << "Cancelled" << std::endl;
    pthread_join(th, nullptr);
    std::cout << "Joined" << std::endl;
}

or
#include <csignal>
#include <mutex>
#include <print>

void *routine(void *arg) {
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, nullptr);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, nullptr);

    int value;
    printf("Reading\n");
    scanf("%u", &value);
    printf("Reading done\n");
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th, nullptr, routine, nullptr);

    usleep(1000000);
    printf("Cancelling thread\n");
    pthread_cancel(th);
    printf("Cancelled\n");
    pthread_join(th, nullptr);
    printf("Joined\n");
}

with output
Reading
Cancelling thread
Cancelled


routine is trying to read value from standard input and I'd like to cancel it.
MacOS, G++ or Clang
I would expect routine thread to be cancelled when pthread_cancel is called but it is not

The program works as expected on Linux (Fedora 40). I suspect that MacOS std::cin retries read on EINTR. In general, mixing pthread_cancel with C++ will end badly.

changing from c++ streams to scanf/printf didn't work out

In general, the first rule of pthread_cancel is never call pthread_cancel. Not in C or in C++, or via any other language's binding.  Thread cancellation in general and pthread_cancel in particular are absolutely rife with pitfalls.  Your development effort is better spent on finding a reliable alternative than on trying to get reliable and safe preemptive thread cancellation.

Mixing pthread_cancel with scanf will end badly for the same reason. If you have any hope of getting this to work, you'll need to limit yourself to read. But, as @JohnBollinger said, better not use pthread_cancel at all.
